# Rotation MKMapView without Upside-Down Labels

Tags: objective-c, ios6, mkmapview, mapkit, cgaffinetransform

### UPDATE

Apple fixed this is iOS 7. More info after public launch.

---

So, I have this bit of code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degToRad([newHeading trueHeading]));
    [mapView setTransform: transform];
}
```

Which beautifully renders directionally rotated map, like so:

[image]

Problem is, the labels are all upside down. Now, I'm pretty sure one can work around this, because I believe Apple touted the ability to rotate labels in an iOS 6 keynote. I'm just not seeing how.

For comparison, the effect I'd like, as implemented in the stock Maps app:

[image]

#### TL;DR

How do I rotate the map, but keep the labels right-side up?
Or at least rotate the labels independently of the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying a transformation onto the map is not the correct way to apply user heading rotations. Metaphorically speaking you're rotating the *entire* canvas instead of the elements on the canvas.

What you want to do is to call:
`[mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:YES];`
(for instance in your viewDid/WillAppear method or some IBAction trigger method.

You can read more about it here:
 http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/setUserTrackingMode:animated:

By calling above method you tell the map view to start updating the heading (rotation). Label rotations will then adjust automagically.

Comment: See, the only problem with using this is I don't want it to turn based on user heading _exactly_, but only at certain points. Say the bottom image (Maps.app) was @ 275°, I only want my map rotated 270° (3*PI/2). So just telling the map view to follow the user isn't quite sufficient.

Comment: Disappointed that this appears to be the only possible outcome. Hope Apple changes this. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @pcperini if you rotate a paper map, the labels are rotated, too. so this nothing to worry much.